# Display property keys containing unicode characters

Tags: unicode

Given a property list with a key containing a unicode character, for example

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  ℂ=1,
  C=2,
}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{l}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  #1 => #2 \\
  $#1$ => #2 \\
}
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The output reads
[image]

In order to have the first key displayed, I must use math mode. But I would like to avoid that. How can I use normal mode to display keys, and fall back to math mode when the normal mode displays nothing ?

Comment: you don't need math mode, just a font that has the characters, latin modern math would work for example.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a font that has the characters, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\tracinglostchars=2
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  ℂ=1,
  C=2,
}
%\ttfamily
\fontspec{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  #1 => #2 \\
  $#1$ => #2 \\
}
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

If you also want it to be monospace, then the choice is probably rather more restricted. Although you could force monospacing by using a luatex virtual font or by forcing the spacing via tex macros

Comment: I came across font JuliaMono that answers the question